# spinner headline change or delete

Tags: android, android-layout

how can i delete or change the text from @2131034112 to "Auswahl" 
i don't know whencesoever the @213... comes from.

java:

```
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStd);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinnerZeitauswahl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml:

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerStd"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.53"
            android:prompt="@array/spinnerZeitauswahl"
             />
```

---

string:

```
       <string-array name="spinnerZeitauswahl">
       <item>Manuell</item>
       <item>1 Std</item>
       <item>2 Std</item>
       <item>3 Std</item>
       <item>4 Std</item>
       <item>5 Std</item>
       <item>6 Std</item>
       <item>7 Std</item>
       <item>8 Std</item>
       <item>9 Std</item>
       <item>10 Std</item>
       <item>11 Std</item>
       <item>12 Std</item>
      </string-array>
```

---

[image: Spinner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this line to your code.

```
spinner .setPrompt("Auswahl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you defined that Spinner, but at least in XML you need to define the `prompt` attribute:

```
  <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="Auswahl"
  />
```

From code you can call `spinner.setPrompt("Auswahl")` too.

Comment: i have paste the xml of the spinner